# List in Reflector

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

The MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) say List collections derive from:

> System.Collections.Generic.List

But when I pull up .NET Reflector 6 this is what I see in `System.Collections.Generic`:

> BitHelper
>
> ISet
>
> LinkedList
>
> LinkedListNode
>
> Queue
>
> SortedDictionary
>
> ...

But no List.

If I right-click on `System.Collections.Generic` and then on "Search MSDN" it [lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic) all of the generic classes and includes List.

But I don't see List in `.Net Reflector.`

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LinkedList<T>` and the other classes you mention are in the `System.dll` assembly.  `List<T>` is in `mscorlib`.  All are in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Make sure to browse to the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace section within `mscorlib`, not `System`.

You can see this [on MSDN's page for `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) right under the namespace definition:

> Namespace:  System.Collections.Generic
>
> Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

However, [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), for example, shows:

> Namespace:  System.Collections.Generic
>
> Assembly:  System (in System.dll)

(Note that you can also search for the type in Reflector, which will cause it to be found correctly...)